# ul li dropdown menu won't show li items after clicking any li item

Tags: javascript, jquery

code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/C5mTf/49/
I am not sure why. Is there any issue with the following codes?

```
$("#menu").on('click','li',function (){
    var current = $(this).text();
    $('li.top').text('Sort: ' + current);
    $('.item').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code working is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/C5mTf/55/

---

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var first = $(this).find("li").eq(1);
    $('li.top').text('Sort: ' + first.text());

    $(".top").on("click mouseover", function(){
        $('.item').show();
    });

    $("#menu").on('click', '.item', function(){
        $('li.top').text('Sort: ' + $(this).text());
        $('.item').hide();
    });
});
```

---

Comment: Please offer some explanation of your changes and additions. Also, shouldn't your `on()` functions be inside the document.ready function?

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: @isherwood it should i suppose. But fiddle wrap everything in document ready so is like there are two document ready functions.

Comment: Still a small bug. When I move the mouse over menu, it should auto display all li items.

Comment: Ok.. I did it in a better way now... Try if this is what you want